# Simulate array with scatter & known relation to X

Tags: r, correlation, simulate, scatter

This is a very basic R question, but I can't seem to find the right packages to do what I want.

I have an array 'X', with n values. I want to simulate an array, 'Y', that follows a known relation Y = alpha + beta*X. Furthermore, I want to add intrinsic scatter to the Y array. Alpha, beta, and the intrinsic scatter should be input values by the user.

Can someone help me with how I would go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that creates the deterministic part of the correlation and then adds noise via `rnorm`

```
make_correlation <- function(alpha, beta, scatter, x){
  # make deterministic part
  y_det <- alpha + beta*x
  # add noise
  y <- rnorm(length(x), y_det, scatter)
  return(y)
}

set.seed(20)
x <- runif(20, 0, 10)

answer <- make_correlation(alpha = 2, beta = 3, scatter = 2, x)
```

plot(answer~x)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think my main confusion stems from the true meaning of intrinsic scatter. Mathematically, Y = a + bx + e, where e is the intrinsic random scatter of Y about the line. So to create such a line, you pick Y values from a gaussian distribution centered on a+bx and that has a stdev = e?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did.   For linear regression you would assume that the error (or intrinsic random scatter) is normally distributed and does not change with the mean.  You could do it with one line of code as well `y <- alpha + beta*x + rnorm(length(x),0, scatter)` if you wanted.  This would just add random variation with a mean at zero.  Anyways, if the answer is adequate make sure to upvote it so that it is considered solved.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
> x <- 1:5
> alpha <- 2
> beta <- 3
> y <- alpha + beta * x
> y
[1]  5  8 11 14 17
```

And by "scatter" do you mean random noise? You can simulate that by added random values like so (I am using a normal distribution) :

```
> y <- alpha + beta * x + rnorm(5)
> y
[1]  4.710538  7.700785 10.588489 14.252223 16.108079
```